# Сохранение данных со скрипта в mysql (рейтинг для сайта)

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

В общем нужно сделать рейтинг для сайта, вот html код:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CollectionPage" class="ratingHolder">
            <div class="userRatingHolder">
                <div class="userRating">
                    <div class="votingHolder">
                        <div data-score="5" class="vote onestar"></div>
                        <div data-score="4" class="vote twostar"></div>
                        <div data-score="3" class="vote threestar"></div>
                        <div data-score="2" class="vote fourstar"></div>
                        <div data-score="1" class="vote fivestar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="passiveRatingHolder">
                 <div class="ratingBg"></div>
                 <div style="width: 85%;" class="ratingMask"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="text">Ваш голос учтен!</div>
            <div class="rateNumbers">
                <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
                    <span itemprop="ratingValue" class="ratingvalue">4.25</span>
                    /
                    <span itemprop="bestRating" class="bestrating">5.00</span>
                    <div class="br"></div>
                    (
                    <span itemprop="reviewCount" class="commentscount">4</span>
                    голосов)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Вот код обработчика:

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('.vote').on ('click', function(){

                $(this).addClass('active');

                var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
                var commentCountElement = parent.find('.commentscount');
                var ratingValueElement = parent.find('.ratingvalue');
                var votedValue = parseInt($(this).attr('data-score'));

                parent.addClass('voted');

                var commentCount = parseInt(commentCountElement.text());
                commentCountElement.text(commentCount + 1);

                var rating = parseFloat(ratingValueElement.text());
                rating = (commentCount * rating + votedValue)/(commentCount + 1);
                ratingValueElement.text(rating.toFixed(2));

                console.log('AJAX запрос примет значение ' + votedValue);

            })
        })
    </script>
```

Всё работает, но нужно сделать сохранение этого рейтинга. Как сохранить переменные со скрипта в БД понятия не имею. Есть у кого какие идеи?

Comment: Ну вы и наворотили, столько кода для 5 звездочек... Дальше jquery ajax post; на php принимаете $_POST['name']; и дальше dbo или mysql_query пишете в базу

Comment: Не совсем понял как на php принять, можно чуть подробнее?)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.external.php

Comment: Так а причем тут post если у меня нет формы?)

Comment: post не только формы принимает, а любые post запросы.

Comment: Еще вместо сотни `parent().parent()` можно использовать `closest('.ratingHolder')`

Comment: @Moonvvell да там вообще все это в 3 строчки пишется, как в js так и в html

Comment: Всё-ровно ничего не получается.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример ajax запроса:

```
//Вместо ajax.php указать свой скрипт оброботчик
$.post( "ajax.php", { votedValue: votedValue })
    .done(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
});
```

Вот пример скрипта php:

```
<?php

$voted_value = $_POST['votedValue'];

//Здесь параметры подключения к вашей БД
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");

//Вывод ошибки
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//Подготовка запроса для защиты от инъекций, здесь указать данные своей таблицы в БД.
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (voted_value) VALUES(?)")) {

    //Подстановка значения вместо ?
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $voted_value);

    //Выполнение запроса
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();
}

$mysqli->close();

//Возвращение javascript скрипту чего нибудь
echo $voted_value;
```